# Filter data from Stream in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Stream which contains List of objects. i.e. `List<ProductSubCategoryListModel>` and
`ProductSubCategoryListModel` contains `isSelected` boolean and `CategoryId` int.

I want to filter Stream which only has `isSelected == true` and get list type of `List<ProductSubCategoryListModel>` in return. After this need to get all the CategoryId from `List.

Here's my code.

```
  Future<void> fetchProducts(
  TrendingCategoriesModel categoryModel, int pageIndex) async {
_localCategoryModel = categoryModel;

//Stream I want to manipulate to get List<ProductSubCategoryListModel>
var stream = _categoryListController.stream;

var request = ProductListRequestModel();
var searchParameterModel = SearchParams();
searchParameterModel.SearchText = '';
searchParameterModel.CategoryIDs = //List<int> of CategoryIds filtered from List<ProductSubCategoryListModel>;
searchParameterModel.SubCategoryIDs = null;
searchParameterModel.AttributeIDs = null;
searchParameterModel.SubAttributeIDs = null;
searchParameterModel.StartPrice = 0;
searchParameterModel.EndPrice = null;
searchParameterModel.EndPrice = null;

request.PageIndex = pageIndex;
request.PageSize = 10;
request.SortExpression = '';
request.SortType = '';
request.IsGetFilterData = true;
request.searchParams = searchParameterModel;

if (!_productListController.isClosed) _productListController.sink.add(null);
var response =
    await _networkHandler.callAPI(NetworkUrl.PRODUCT_LIST, request);
if (response != null) {
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use map method https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/map.html. it returns new stream with mapped data. Map will be applied to each event in a stream.

Additionally you can apply distinct method https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/distinct.html just after map, if you need to ensure that only unique values will be emitted to the subscriber

Answer (score 0):

You can use **where** method of stream which will return only whose elements that has isSelected flag true.

```
var stream = _categoryListController.stream;

  stream = stream.where((element) {
    return element
        .isSelected;
  }).toList();
```